# How to manually control animation frame by frame?

Tags: three.js

Regarding this Three.js example https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes I was able to load my own model and play animation in a loop. However I want to make a "slider" that will allow user to control animation frame by frame. How I can achieve this with AnimationMixer? Let's say that animation clip has duration 4s. I would like to control in realtime current animation time from 0s to 4s.

Comment: Maybe the following example is a good starting point. It allows you to record and control an animation with a timeline interface: https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_animation_authoring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is right there in the code of the example you linked:

```
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );
mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] ).play();

// ...

function animate() {
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    mixer.update( delta );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```

`mixer.update( delta );` is what updates the animation by 0.0166 seconds on every frame (at 60FPS). If you want to jump to a specific moment, simply assign the [.time](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer.time) property to whatever second you need.

[See here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer) for more documentation on AnimationMixer.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is incomplete. It would never work with a slider input as described in the original post. The problem is that the Animation Mixer update function changes the time relative to the current time and is subsequently unsuitable for a slider input as described.

Instead you want to make a function like this:

```
  function seekAnimationTime(animMixer, timeInSeconds){
    animMixer.time=0;
    for(var i=0;i<animMixer._actions.length;i++){
      animMixer._actions[i].time=0;
    }
    animMixer.update(timeInSeconds)
  }
```

With this you could then run this in your slider OnChange event listener:

```
seekAnimationTime(yourAnimationMixer, event.value);
```

Or to set the animation time to 2s:

```
seekAnimationTime(yourAnimationMixer,2);
```

This solution will work regardless of what the previous animationMixer time was.

Answer (score 1):

[Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865303/2578205) is correct; to achieve what is described with a slider input control (i.e. like scrubbing a video) then the [`AnimationMixer.update` method](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer.update) is not appropriate.

Fortunately, there now exists a [`AnimationMixer.setTime` method](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer.setTime) to accomplish this.
It is implemented essentially as [Alexander described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865303/2578205), which you can see here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r130/src/animation/AnimationMixer.js#L649-L661

**Scrub/slide to an exact time in seconds:**

```
mixer.setTime( exactTimeInSeconds )
```

**Move forward in time by `delta` amount of seconds**:

Using the [`Clock.getDelta` method](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Clock.getDelta) to get seconds passed since last call:

```
const delta = clock.getDelta(); // Optional: In this case we get delta from Three.js' own clock instead of a slider
mixer.update( delta );
```

**All Together**

To tie this all together, consider an example scenario where we want to get to the 3 second mark:

```
mixer.setTime(2); // time = 2 second mark
mixer.update(1); // time = 2 + 1 = 3 second mark
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created some code that allows stepping the animation *by percentage* from 0% to 100%. You can find the JavaScript version below, or a [TypeScript version here](https://github.com/frostoven/Cosmosis/blob/ba8f1d8cd7fab935f56747dde791793f04f75b9b/app/local/AnimationSlider.ts).

To my knowledge, three.js doesn't have per-frame stepping, but rather general interpolation info (though I could be wrong about that). IMO percentage-based seeking is more useful anyway as it allows consistent stepping regardless of mesh frame count.

| Example Blender animation: | Controlling frame position by percentage with an external device: |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

### The code:

```js
/**
 * Class that offers a means of controlling an animation by percentage.
 */
class AnimationSlider {
  constructor(mesh) {
    this._fakeDelta = 0;
    this._mesh = mesh;
    this._mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(mesh.scene);
    this._clips = mesh.animations;
    this._percentage = 0;

    this.anims = [];
    for (let i = 0, len = this._clips.length; i < len; i++) {
      const clip = this._clips[i];
      const action = this._mixer.clipAction(clip);
      action.play();
      action.paused = true;
      //
      this.anims.push({ clip, action });
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sets the animation to an exact point.
   * @param percentage - A number from 0 to 1, where 0 is 0% and 1 is 100%.
   */
  seek(percentage) {
    if (this._percentage === percentage) {
      return;
    }

    for (let i = 0, len = this.anims.length; i < len; i++) {
      const { clip, action } = this.anims[i];
      action.time = percentage * clip.duration;
      this._mixer.update(++this._fakeDelta);
    }

    this._percentage = percentage;
  }
}
```

### Example usage:

```js
// Create a slider instance:
const slider = new AnimationSlider(gltfMesh);

// Set the animation position to 40%:
slider.seek(0.4);
```

I believe that the code is self-explanatory, but if not, let me know and I'll riddle it with comments.